# How to make the program read any file when compiling

Tags: java, file, args

I need the program read any text file when i run it in a terminal, so if it should look something like:

java TextAnalysis in01.txt and when I hit enter.
I know everything compiles right if I have a specific text file read by the scanner. But when I tried replacing the file by args[0], it stopped compiled, and gave me an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: in01.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:636)
    at TextAnalysis.main(TextAnalysis.java:17)
```

Source:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TextAnalysis {

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = args[0];
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
        int MAX_WORDS = 10000;
        String[] words = new String[MAX_WORDS];
        int unique = 0;

        System.out.println("TEXT FILE STATISTICS");
        System.out.println("--------------------");
        System.out.println("Length of the longest word: " + longestWord(fileScanner));
        read(words, fileName);
        System.out.println("Number of words in file wordlist: " + wordList(words));
        System.out.println("Number of words in file: " + countWords(fileName));
        System.out.println("Word-frequency statistics");

    }


    public static String longestWord (Scanner s) {
        String longest = "";
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String word = s.next();
            if (word.length() > longest.length()) {
                longest = word;
            }
        }
        return (longest.length() + " " + "(\"" + longest + "\")");
    }

    public static int countWords (String fileName) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file); 
        int count = 0;

            while(fileScanner.hasNext()) {
                String word = fileScanner.next();
                    count++;
            }
        return count;
    }


    public static void read(String[] words, String fileName) throws IOException{
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
        while (s.hasNext()) {
        String word = s.next();
        int i;
        for ( i=0; i < words.length && words[i] != null; i++ ) {
            words[i]=words[i].toLowerCase();
            if (words[i].equals(word)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        words[i] = word;
    }
    }

    public static int wordList(String[] words) {
        int count = 0;
        while (words[count] != null) {
            count++;
        }
     return count; 
    }

}
```

Comment: And the `in01.txt` file exists at the same location you executed the class from?

Comment: Also try using an absolute path than a relative one.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in your file name which makes java interpreted your arguments as the array {TextAnalysis,in01}. The simple way to fix this is to make the space in the file name a underscore.

Comment: You mean type java TextAnalysis_in01.txt into the terminal? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Because your file in01.txt does not exists,when you try to use a Scanner from this file,exception was thrown.

Make sure there is a file named in01.txt in the same directory as the TextAnalysis.class does.

Comment: oops, you're right, i didn't realize it was in another folder. Thank you